# Get POST event in JavaScript but not Ajaxa (symfony4.1)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am looking for some event to handle, witch get if something is post by php. Not Ajax request, but if php i.e. post form. 
I just wanna do some spinner if this situation happen's. Normal in Javascript i know it's easy:

```
 $(document).on({
  ajaxStart: function() {   $('#page-loader').removeClass('p-hidden');  },
   ajaxStop: function() {       $('#page-loader').addClass('p-hidden'); }
});
```

But how to handle php post request and use like this upper for ajax? any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery to hook onto the  submit event:

```
$('#formId').on('submit', function(event) {
    // Start animation spinner
});
```

Comment: oh, yeah... was to tired to think about it :P so easy ... yep ! thanks :P